# How can I get a negative value of CSS variables (aka Custom Properties)

Tags: css, css-variables, css-calc

Let me start by showing you how I would do this in SCSS:

```
$submenu-padding-left: 1.5em;

transform: translateX(calc(-#{$submenu-padding-left} + .5em));
```

which would compile to:

```
transform: translateX(calc(-1.5em - .5em))
```

Basically SCSS allows me to concatenate a minus symbol `-` with a variable in order to convert it to a negative value.

Is it possible to achieve this with CSS Variables?

Comment: "How to concatenate a minus symbol with CSS Variable in a calc()" As you've seen, that's not the correct way to approach the problem. You never concatenate anything in a calc() expression. You can, however, concatenate var() expressions just about everywhere else.

Comment: @TemaniAfif That is a fair point, both answers are basically the same - because you answered first I have marked your answer as the accepted one again.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

Yes you can do it. Simply multiply by `-1`:

```css
:root {
  --margin: 50px;
}

body {
  margin: 0 100px;
  border:1px solid;
}

.box-1 {
  background: red;
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
  margin-left: calc(-1 * var(--margin));
}

.box-2 {
  background: green;
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
  margin-left: calc(-1 * (-1 * var(--margin))); /* You can also nest calculation */
}
```

```html
<div class="box-1">
</div>
<div class="box-2">
</div>
```

Comment: Did you intentionally show a calc() example that negated itself? `margin-left: calc(-1 * (-1 * var(--margin)));` is the same as `margin-left: var(--margin);`  Perhaps `margin-left: calc(2 * (-1 * var(--margin)));` would be a better demonstration?

Comment: @TimR I wanted to have a double negation

Answer (score 9):

If you need negative value multiple times then you can define a new variable:

```
:root {
  --margin: 50px;
  --margin--: calc(var(--margin) * -1);
 /* 
 while you may simply write like below
 but I love to use as above 
 coz, we'll only need to change value 
 in one place if needed
 */
 /* --margin--: -50px; */
}

.positive-margin {
  margin: var(--margin);
}
.negative-margin {
  margin-left: var(--margin--);
}
```

You can use `--margin-` or `--negative-margin` instead of `--margin--`. But I preferred this because of readability.

Answer (score 2):

another possible way:

```
.negative-margin {
    margin-left: calc(0px - var(--margin));
}
```